# Angular 2 upgrading to Angular 4 - Having issues with npm modules, trying to downgrade, now getting sass loader issues

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

I tried upgrading from Angular 2.4.1 -> Angular 4, and I ran into a bunch of errors related to some of my npm modules, so I decided to downgrade back to what I had. The problem now is that even after I reverted my package.json to my previous version, removed `node_modules` and ran `npm install`, I'm getting these errors now and I have no idea why:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/styles.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css' in '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rosebud-web/src'
 @ ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/styles.scss 3:10-190
 @ ./src/styles.scss
 @ multi ./src/styles.scss ./~/ng2-toasty/style-default.css
```

Is there something else I need to do? I didn't touch anything with the css loaders, yet they are messed up.

```
Here is is my package.json info:

"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.1.31",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.36",
    "@types/request": "0.0.30",
    "angular2-focus": "^1.1.0",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.3.0",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "^2.2.0",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^3.6.6",
    "firebase-queue": "^1.5.0",
    "jspdf": "^1.3.3",
    "lodash": "^4.15.0",
    "ng-semantic": "^1.1.13",
    "ng2-datepicker": "^1.8.2",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-toasty": "^4.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.32.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.21",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.4",
    "firebase-server": "^0.9.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.4.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, delete all contents from node_modules folder then run "npm install" again.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that you're importing font-awesome, but your package.json doesn't show it being installed.  Something previously may have required it as a dependency, which is why it showed up in your node_modules and no longer does.